# Javascript Function.prototype.bind which this is this / how to find this

Tags: javascript

If I don't use bind when binding to an event I know the "this" refers to the calling object. If I use bind then I can make the "this" reflect the class the method exists in. Now my question is if I use bind so that "this" refers to the class that the method is in is there a way to refer to the calling object now that "this" is referencing the class?

eg:

```
//inside me.handleClick "this" will refer to obj
obj.attachEvent("onclick", this.handleClick); 

//inside this.handleClick "this" will refer to the object that handleClick is a member of. how do I get a reference to obj inside handleClick?
obj.attachEvent("onclick", this.handleClick.bind(this));
```

I hope this question makes sense as my head is spinning with all the "this" references.

Comment: `this` does *not* refer to the class, but to the **instance** that the method is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Event Data

When you add event handlers to an element, javascript passes in an event object as a parameter to that function. In this object is a proeprty called `toElement` that stores the element that called this event.

Here is a way to bind the object to the event and keep track of the element still.
The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZXhL/1/

#### JS

```
//The constructor
var Button = function(selector) {
    this.element = document.querySelector(selector)
    //Bind both events
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.handler1)
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.handler2.bind(this))
}

Button.prototype.handler1 = function() {
    console.log("Handler 1")
    console.log(this) //Should be <button>
}

Button.prototype.handler2 = function(e) {
    console.log("Handler 2")
    console.log(this) //Will be the button object in js
    console.log(e.currentTarget) //will be the <button> element
}

var button = new Button("button")
```

You can clean up this code even further by using the special function handleEvent
MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZXhL/2/

```
var Button = function(selector) {
    this.element = document.querySelector(selector)
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this)
}

Button.prototype.handleEvent = function(e) {
    console.log("Using handleEvent")
    console.log(this)
    console.log(e.currentTarget) 
}

var button = new Button("button")
```

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to think there must be something in the event that would return the element. I haven't used .toElement before I'd only used .target and .srcElement for dealing with bubbling before.

Comment: After doing some more research into this the toElement wouldn't work if the object that had the event registered had child objects. This webpage shows that you would need to compare and see if the toElement or .target equaled the event.currentTarget to see if it is the one that the event was registered on or I would have to loop up through the parents till I found the .currentTarget to find the parent that the event was registered with.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljeqmgmn.php

Comment: Good find, changed my answer to use currentTarget. Amazing how close all of those properties are to each other. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
var that = this;
obj.attachEvent("onclick", function() {
    that.handleClick(this);
});
```

- You can't directly call a method on an object because `this` always refers to the DOM Element in an event. That's why you need an anonymous function.
- `that` is required to create another reference to your object because you're not in the same context (remember: inside the anonymous function, `this` refers to the DOM element `obj`).

After that, in `handleClick`, `this` will refer to your custom object, while the first argument passed to the method will be `obj` (e.q. the DOM element).

Note that `attachEvent` is specific to Internet Explorer. You have to use `addEventListener` to work with all browsers.

Comment: I've used the anonymous function approach before I was more specifically looking for an answer in relation to using bind.